Is there limited quantization in all models? For example you can take a standard model like meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B and run it at half (float16?)
I'm just trying to understand how quantization is setup in all the models.
Standard models like meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B can be run without quantization (bfloat16 or float32?), or they can be told to run at half (float16?) with an inferencing app (like vLLM). So does that mean there is some quantization build into all models? Instead of telling it to run at half quantization, can I instead say int8? Or does that only work if the model was built for it?
And then there are models that are specifically built for int4 (i.e. meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct-SpinQuant_INT4_EO8). Does that mean that when you run this model with vLLM, you have to explicitly say you are running it at int4, or you just leave that at default and it will automatically run at int4? Can that be overridden to int8? Or is it just hardcoded for int4?
Just been trying to wrap my head around this for the past 2 days.

Conceptually, lower number of bits adds noise (quantization) which is translated for the LLM to less "accurate" result - for same probability of success higher probability of failure. When you are calculating long vectors MAC/DOT-PRODUCT floating might suffer from Castrophic-failure where could be avoided by utilizing large accumulators for fixed multiplications (for 1000 vector length, 8X8 multiply could be fully accurate with 26 bit accumulators). For most cases an 8X8 is well sufficient.
